# How to join two tables by multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables named `Evaluation` and `Value`.

In both tables, there are four columns. But three of the four are the same. In other words, they both have the `CaseNum`, `FileNum`, `ActivityNum` columns. In addition to those, the `Evaluation` table has the `Grade` column, and the `Value` table has the `Score` column.

I want to merge the two into one table, joining by `CaseNum`, `FileNum`, and `ActivityNum`, so I have a new table of five columns, including `Value` and `Score`.

Can I use `INNER JOIN` multiple times to do this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Yes: You can use `Inner Join`** to join on multiple columns.

```
SELECT E.CaseNum, E.FileNum, E.ActivityNum, E.Grade, V.Score from Evaluation E
INNER JOIN Value V
ON E.CaseNum = V.CaseNum AND
    E.FileNum = V.FileNum AND 
    E.ActivityNum = V.ActivityNum
```

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE MyNewTab(CaseNum int, FileNum int,
    ActivityNum int, Grade int, Score varchar(100))
```

Insert values

```
INSERT INTO MyNewTab Values(CaseNum, FileNum, ActivityNum, Grade, Score)
SELECT E.CaseNum, E.FileNum, E.ActivityNum, E.Grade, V.Score from Evaluation E
INNER JOIN Value V
ON E.CaseNum = V.CaseNum AND
    E.FileNum = V.FileNum AND 
    E.ActivityNum = V.ActivityNum
```

Answer (score 8):

No, just include the different fields in the "ON" clause of 1 inner join statement:

```
SELECT * from Evalulation e JOIN Value v ON e.CaseNum = v.CaseNum
    AND e.FileNum = v.FileNum AND e.ActivityNum = v.ActivityNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to do a single join:

```
SELECT e.Grade, v.Score, e.CaseNum, e.FileNum, e.ActivityNum
FROM Evaluation e
INNER JOIN Value v ON e.CaseNum = v.CaseNum AND e.FileNum = v.FileNum AND e.ActivityNum = v.ActivityNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You would basically want something along the lines of:

```
SELECT e.*, v.Score
  FROM Evaluation e
LEFT JOIN Value v
ON v.CaseNum = e.CaseNum AND
v.FileNum = e.FileNum AND
v.ActivityNum = e.ActivityNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.CaseNum, E.FileNum, E.ActivityNum, E.Grade, V.Score
FROM Evaluation E
INNER JOIN Value V
ON E.CaseNum = V.CaseNum AND E.FileNum = V.FileNum AND E.ActivityNum = V.ActivityNum
```