# Join a Composite Foreign key using SQL?

Tags: sql

I was wondering if there is a way to INNER JOIN By matching COMPOSITE FOREIGN KEY table with COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY TABLE or vice versa

For example I have a table "SHIFT_INFO" with composite primary keys (MACHINE,LOGINTIME). The columns are MACHINE,LOGINTIME,EMPLOYEE,PART,DURATION,GOODPARTS

I have a table with PRIMARY/FOREIGN KEYS (MACHINE,LOGINTIME). The columns are MACHINE,LOGINTIME,EMPLOYEE,PART, DEFECT1_count,DEFECT2_count,DEFECT3_count,Total_Defects

Lets say I want to join SHIFT_INFO to include Total_Defects. How can I do this?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Probably `join table T2 on T2.Column1 = T1.Column1 and T2.Column2 = T1.Column2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Join two tables by multiple columns in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916741/how-to-join-two-tables-by-multiple-columns-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a `JOIN` you don't need a foreign key. That would be:

```
select si.*, t2.total_defects
from table2 t2 join
     shift_info si
     on si.machine = t2.machine and si.logintime = t2.logintime;
```

If you wanted to add a foreign key constraint, that would be:

```
alter table table2 add constraint fk_table2_shift_info
    foreign key (machine, logintime) references shift_info(machine, logintime);
```

Comment: Got it, What is the point of using Foreign Keys then If i Don't need them to do joins?

Comment: @DylanDevotta . . . They guarantee data integrity in the database.